# Why does kotlin flow not trigger the transform function after an error is handled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow, kotlin-flow-flatmaplatest

I have the below code in my view model class.

```
class MarketViewModel @Inject constructor(repo: MarketRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val retry = MutableStateFlow(0)

    val marketState: LiveData<State<Market>> =
        retry.flatMapLatest{repo.refreshMarket()}
        .map { State.Success(it) as State<T> }
        .catch { error -> emit(State.Error(error)) }
        .stateIn(vmScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), State.Loading())
        .asLiveData()

    fun retry() {
        retry.value++
    }
}

MarketRepository.kt:

    fun refreshMarket() =
        flow { emit(api.getMarkets()) }
            .onEach { db.upsert(it) }
            .flowOn(dispatchers.IO)
```

It works fine until a network error occurs in the repository method `refreshMarket` then when I call the retry() on the view model, it doesn't trigger the `flatMapLatest` transformer function anymore on the retry `MutableStateFlow`, why?

Does the flow get complete when it calls a `Catch` block? how to handle such situation?

Comment: As a side note, why does `refreshMarket` give a flow of one element? What's the point of such complexity as opposed to a simple suspend function?

Comment: @Joffrey, It's not one element flow, it returns Loading, Error, Cached, Init states as well, I excluded that for brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, `catch` won't continue emitting after an exception is caught. As [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/catch.html) says, it is conceptually similar to wrapping all the code above it in `try`. If there is a loop in a traditional `try` block, it does not continue iterating once something is thrown, for example:

```
try {
    for (i in 1..10) {
        if (i == 2) throw RuntimeException()
        println(i)
    }
} catch (e: RuntimeException) {
    println("Error!")
}
```

In this example, once 2 is encountered, the exception is caught, but code flow does not return to the loop in the `try` block. You will not see any numbers printed that come after 2.

You can use `retryWhen` instead of `catch` to be able to restart the flow. To do it on demand like you want, maybe this strategy could be used (I didn't test it):

```
class MarketViewModel @Inject constructor(repo: MarketRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val retry = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>()

    val marketState: LiveData<State<Market>> =
        repo.refreshMarket()
        .map { State.Success(it) as State<T> }
        .retryWhen { error, _ -> 
            emit(State.Error(error))
            retry.first() // await next value from retry flow
            true
        }
        .stateIn(vmScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), State.Loading())
        .asLiveData()

    fun retry() {
        retry.tryEmit(Unit)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But I think the Kotlin team should do a better job with it as it's a common pattern to provide a retry/refresh option to the user when an API fails and having to workaround with this kind of a hacky way would be troublesome and will lead to a bug hunting game.

Comment: It would only work with `emit()` instead of `tryEmit()`. `tryEmit()` will not emit if downstream is await.

Comment: I think you could also use .catch *inside* your flatMapLatest to get it working. Might be simpler than my idea above. And there might be an even simpler way we’re not thinking of yet…